# How do I make a button that time stamps INs and OUTs

Tags: sql, ms-access, button

Good evening, I am new to MS Access & I am trying to figure out how to make a button that time stamps IN & OUT times/dates for a day care.  (Also, another one for employees).

I don't know much about coding.  Currently, I've got my ClientID as an employee number and their respective names and info linked to that.

But how do I create a simple to use button interface that would allow an employee to simply enter a name (or search), then click Sign In / Sign Out to time stamp that time to a field of records for me to later query for data, calculate cost of attendance, etc.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question is far too vague. What **specific** part of doing this are you having difficulty with? This is not a programming tutorial site.

Comment: Are you a charity? What do you want to happen next? Look at a default value of Now()